# Config file modification in Deployed EAR

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Is it possible to edit the config files, which are in a deployed EAR? If yes, please let me know how to do that without re-deploying the EAR.

Comment: with or without redeploying the EAR?

Comment: and which application server are you talking about?

Comment: i'm using Websphere 6.1 and want to modify the config files without re-deploying the EAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is WebSphere 6.1, see [Ways to update application files](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/crun_app_upgrade.html), in particular [Hot deployment and dynamic reloading](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/trun_app_hotupgrade.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Websphere and the working directory of EAR file is available to you the config files can be modified but you need to restart the server.Atleast it is less painful than moving across all the six to eight steps of deployment

Better read the Installtion guide to have further understanding